# No me realiza la comparación entre dos variables

Tags: linux, bash, condiciones

Estoy realizando un script en Linux, en el que almaceno en un fichero los usuarios, cuyo UID sea mayor de 1000 y cuya carpeta Documentos supere los 5,0K de almacenamiento. Para ello, utilizo el comando `du`y a su vez, con el comando `cut` obtengo únicamente el valor del almacenamiento. Aquí el comando:

```
bytes=$(du -h /home/$usuario/Documentos |cut -d "K" -f1)
```

El comando anterior me devuelve lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se ve en la imagen, devuelve valores como: `4,0` o `8,0`

Después, realizo la comparación para comprobar si supera o no los `5,0`y me da el error que se ve en la imagen:

```
prueba.sh: 16: 4,0:not found
```

El código del script es el siguiente:

```
#!/bin/bash

for uid in $(cat /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f3);do
        if [ $uid -ge 1000 ]:
        then
                if [ $uid -le 1500 ]:
                then

                usuario=$(grep -E $uid /etc/passwd | cut -d ":" -f1)
                echo Almacenamiento del directorio /Documentos del $usuario
                bytes=$(du -h /home/$usuario/Documentos | cut -d "K" -f1)
                echo $bytes
                echo ================================================

                max=5,0
                if [ $($bytes > $max) ]:
                then
                        echo $usuario >> usuarios.txt
                fi
                fi
        fi
done


cat usuarios.txt
```

También he probado ha realizar la comparación utilizando `-le` y el error que aparece es el siguiente:

```
prueba.sh: 16: [: Illegal number: 4,0
```

Mis deducciones me hacen pensar que tiene algo que ver con el tipo de variable, es probable que $bytes esté almacenando una string mientras que `$max` es un `integer`. No obstante, he buscado y rebuscado y consigo encontrar la manera de convertir `$bytes` en integer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tu script tiene muchas irregularidades. Te sugiero que le des una mejor leída a manuales en internet o en `man bash`. Si tienes duda con algún comando puedes ejecutar `man <nombre del comando>` o, si es un *built-in* de bash, puedes utilizar `help <comando>`.

Una irregularidad es que usas el token `:` después del bloque de comparación, lo cual no tiene sentido en `bash` ya que lo interpreta como un `hacer nada y devolver un estado de salida 0`. Quizás lo confundes con su uso en funciones o ciclos en lenguajes como `python`.

Otra irregularidad es que el usar `cut` para obtener el tamaño de los archivos es una muy mala idea, porque pudiera tener otros sufijo o no tener alguno.

Otra es que utilizas el token `>` para comparar dentro del *built-in* `[`, lo cual por un lado no funciona como crees, y en el caso de que funcionara (por ciertas excepciones) lo haría sobre una comparación que no tiene sentido que sería la salida de `du ... | cut -d "K" ...` comparando con el string `5,0`. Es decir, comparas cadenas de texto que claramente serán diferentes.

Otra es que utilizas un *command substitution* de una manera un tanto dudosa en tu línea 16. La utilizas, bien, pero ahí no tiene mucho sentido.

Otra es que el uso del `if [ $uid -ge 1000 ]` no tiene sentido si sólo dentro pones únicamente otro bloque de código dentro de un `if [ $uid -le 1500 ]`. Sería mejor que hicieras una condición compuesta o hicieras uso de los operadores lógicos.

Otra es que, ¿Qué pasa si no tiene el directorio `Documentos`? Pues fallaría.

La reescritura del script que te ofrezco es esta; quizás haya otra mejor manera de hacerlo.

```
#!/bin/bash

declare folder_name="Documentos"  #  Así dejamos claro desde el principio sobre
                                  #+ que directorio operaremos.

declare max_kb=5  #  Ponemos la cantidad en kilobytes, o en lo que elijas
                  #+ pero teniendo en cuenta que lo evaluaras después 
                  #+ en esta unidad.
declare archivo_usuarios="./usuarios.txt"

#  Almaceno los UIDS que tengan cuatro o mas caracteres.
#                                          |
#                                          |      
getent passwd | cut -d ":" -f 3 | egrep ".{4,}" \
    | while read uid || [[ -n "$uid" ]]  # Almaceno cada UID en la variable "uid".
do 

    if [[ "$uid" -ge 1000 && "$uid" -le 1500 ]]  #  Creo una condición doble usando el operador
                                                 #+ "&&" que permite el built-in "[[", donde pregunto
                                                 #+ si está el uid entre 1000 y 1500.
    then
        usuario=$(id -un $uid)  #  Uso "id -un $uid" para obtener el nombre del usuario según
                                #+ su UID.
        usuario_home=$(eval "echo ~$usuario")  #  Hacemos una "tilde expansion" para saber el directorio
                                               #+ el directorio home del usuario, ya que no siempre es
                                               #+ /home/usuariox.

        [[ ! -d "$usuario_home/$folder_name" ]] && continue
        #  Si no existe la carpeta <home del usuario>/<folder a buscar>, entonces
        #+ se salta los demás pasos.

        kbytes=$( du -s $usuario_home/$folder_name -k | awk '{print $1}' )  # Obtenemos sólo el tamaño del folder en kilobytes.
        #                          |
        #                          |
        #                          |___ Esta operación se hace sobre <home del usuario>/<folder a buscas>.

        echo "Almacenamiento del directorio \"$folder_name\" de $usuario"
        echo "$kbytes"
        echo ================================================

        [[ "$kbytes" -gt "$max_kb" ]] && echo "$usuario" >> "$archivo_usuarios"
        #  Si $kbytes es mayor que $max_kb, entonces el nombre del usuario
        #+ se añade al archivo $archivo_usuarios.
    fi

done
```

### Con ayuda de `grep` y el uso de expresiones regulares.

Otra opción que te ofrezco es con el uso de `grep -P` y una expresión regular tipo PERL alimentando un `while` con múltiples variables. Así, usando este archivo, podemos evitar comandos como el que utilice de `id` o el tratar de construir el `HOME` del usuario:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare folder_name="Documentos"  #  Así dejamos claro desde el principio sobre
                                 #+ que directorio operaremos.

declare max_kb=5  #  Ponemos la cantidad en kilobytes, o en lo que elijas
                  #+ pero teniendo en cuenta que lo evaluaras después 
                  #+ en esta unidad.

declare archivo_usuarios="./usuarios.txt"

#  Uso en "grep", con las expresiones regulares tipo PERL activadas, una expresión regular
#+ que nos trae los registros que tengan cuatro o más caracteres en el tercer campo, lo 
#+ cual nos trae a los usuarios que tengan un uid de cuatro carateres.
#+ Esto lo hago pensando en no meter registros innecesarios dentro del ciclo.
#              |
#        ______|_____________
#       |                    |
grep -P '^([^:]*:){2}[^:]{4,}' /etc/passwd \
| while 
    IFS=":" 
    read username _passwd uid _gid _comment user_home _interpeter #  Las variables que inician con "_", 
    #       |              |                    |                 #+ no son necesarias para nuestro caso
    #       |              |                    |
    #       |              |                    |_______________ HOME del usuario.
    #       |              |
    #       |              |____________________________________ UID del usuario.
    #       |
    #       |___________________________________________________ Nombre del usuario.                                                            usuario.
do 

    if [[ "$uid" -ge 1000 && "$uid" -le 1500 ]]  #  Creo una condición doble usando el operador
                                                 #+ "&&" que permite el built-in "[[", donde pregunto
                                                 #+ si está el uid entre 1000 y 1500.
    then

        [[ ! -d "$user_home/$folder_name" ]] && continue
        #  Si no existe la carpeta <home del usuario>/<folder a buscar>, entonces
        #+ se salta los demás pasos.

        kbytes=$( du -s $user_home/$folder_name -k | awk '{print $1}' )  # Obtenemos sólo el tamaño del folder en kilobytes.
        #                          |
        #                          |
        #                          |___ Esta operación se hace sobre <home del usuario>/<folder a buscar>.

        cat - << _eof
Almacenamiento del directorio $folder_name de $username"
$kbytes
================================================
_eof

        [[ "$kbytes" -gt "$max_kb" ]] && echo "$username" >> "$archivo_usuarios"
        #  Si $kbytes es mayor que $max_kb, entonces el nombre del usuario
        #+ se añade al archivo $archivo_usuarios.
    fi

done
```

### Con ayuda de `awk` (mi preferida).

Una última opción que te ofrezco es el uso de `awk` para alimentar al `while`:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare folder_name="Documentos"                                   
declare max_kb=5                                      
declare archivo_usuarios="./usuarios.txt"

#      ____ Con -F : le indicas a awk que el separador de campos
#     |     serán los dos puntos.
#     |
#     |
#     |  Con awk te podrías reducir varios pasos, por ejemplo, desde aquí podrías
#     |  permitir únicamente la entrada de registros del fichero /etc/passwd cuyo
#     |  tercer campo (el del uid) esté entre 1000 y 1500. Después puedes alimentar
#     |  al while sólo con los registros que cumplan con esa condición.
#     |               |
#     |   ____________|___________
#     |  |                        |
awk -F : '$3 >= 1000 && $3 <= 1500' /etc/passwd \
 | \
while 
    IFS=":" 
    read username _passwd uid _gid _comment user_home _interpeter #  Las variables que inician con "_", 
    #       |              |                    |                 #+ no son necesarias para nuestro caso
    #       |              |                    |
    #       |              |             HOME del usuario.
    #       |              |
    #       |        UID del usuario.
    #       |
    # Nombre del usuario.
do 

    [[ ! -d "$user_home/$folder_name" ]] && continue

    kbytes=$( du -s $user_home/$folder_name -k | awk '{print $1}' )

    cat - << _eof
Almacenamiento del directorio $folder_name de $username"
$kbytes
================================================
_eof

    [[ "$kbytes" -gt "$max_kb" ]] && echo "$username" >> "$archivo_usuarios"

done
```

Answer (score 2):

revisa el comando `du` ya que por defecto te lo da en `K`:

http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/du1.html

Por tanto si haces:

```
du /home/$usuario/Documentos
```

Ya te lo está mostrando en `K` (pero no sale la letra y te ahorrar el cut) y la variable `max` puede ser `5` y así no tienes problemas con los cambios de tipos.

Del mismo modo, si quieres más control tienes la opción `--block-size=x` que lo puedes poner a `1000` o `1024` para tener control sobre el calculo del peso de los ficheros.

Espero haberte ayudado.